# display all pending notification in a separate view

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

May be this is a childish question, but i am beginer **please do not consider as wrong question.**, i was searching alot, also m following this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html tutorial. and also google to solve my problem but i could't find.

This is my assignment.

I have a EditText and a Button in main activity, When i click the button a notification is generated, when i am opening that notification another activity is open, shows Editext data, which i have entered in the main activity through EditText.

my Question is....

1. I want to Show the count of pending notifications in a single Notification window as in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating
      but i could't understand this --> **Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user....**
     how can i achive this. how can i process data to get the pending count. keep in mind this count will decrement when there is no notification???
2. When click a notification than i want to get all notifications in a separate activity just like a messages in inbox.
3. e.g. in my main activity i am clicking the button 10 times, so actually 10 notifications will generate in a single notification window with count=10, but it shows count = 1?? when i open the notifications than it will only show the latest notification contents in another activity, how can i show remaining 9 in a single activity??

Below in my Main activity....

```
Button btn;
EditText edtText;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CreteNotification(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), edtText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

protected void CreteNotification(long when, String data) {

    String notificationContent ="Notification Content Click Here to go more details";
    String notificationTitle ="This is Notification";
    int number = 1;
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    int smalIcon =R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    String notificationData = data;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("Message", notificationData);
    intent.putExtra("Time", Integer.toString((int) when) );
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"+when));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentText(notificationContent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(notificationTitle)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
    // how to loop??????????????????

    notificationBuilder.setNumber(++number);

    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.getNotification();
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

}
```

code where i want to show all notifications?????

```
    HashMap<String, String> inboxMsg;
TextView notiTextView;
Button btn;
int Id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_notification_class);

    inboxMsg =  new HashMap<String, String>();
    Id = 0;
    notiTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Set<String> keys = inboxMsg.keySet();
            Iterator keyItra = keys.iterator();
            while (keyItra.hasNext()) {
                String k = (String) keyItra.next();
                String Message = inboxMsg.get(k);
                notiTextView.setText(Message);
            }
        }
    });

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        String Mesage  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Message");
        String Time = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Time");
        inboxMsg.put(Integer.toString(++Id), "Message is " + Mesage + " Time " + Time + "\n");
    }
}
```

where is the problem kindly redirect me to the correct path, also kindly guide me how to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not getting the actual notification count is that whenever `CreteNotification(long when, String data)` method is called number variable is set to 1. It can be solved by instead of declaring it inside a method make number a class member variable.

```
Button btn;
EditText edtText;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
int number = 1;

.....

protected void CreteNotification(long when, String data) {
    .....
    notificationBuilder.setNumber(++number);
    ....
}
```

Regarding starting different activity for every notification, you need to pass different 'ID' for each notification when calling `notificationManager.notify(ID, notification);` method, but remember if you assign different ID, triggering new notification won't update the count but add a new notification. So clicking the button for generating notification will actually generate 10 different notifications.

Comment: Waqas i've declred number as a class data member, than its working fine but when later when i click the button again than its set to 1 again???
Regarding 2nd answer i dont want 10 separate notifications, want only 1 notification with count = 10, and when i open the notifications all 10 notifications should be available in a sepate activity???
just like GOSMS Pro, or any other SMS app, which shows total message count in the notification bar, How To do this

Comment: what do you mean by working fine but later it didn't? Regardin 2nd you can't do that because if PendingIntent contains the same data,action,flag etc.. it is is simply replaced.

Comment: so tell me how to achive this, simply 10 notifications is easy but how to process data to retreive all PendingIntents?? is there any way to do????

Comment: ? if you call notification with different ID if will generate 10 different notifications and on tapping on anyof them will start new separate activity

Comment: Waqas if i use notification with differnt ID's than 10 different notifications, than each has differnt contents, but suppose 100 notifications than user will unintall this app is't true?? so simply i want to show all notifications in a single one, clicking on that will show all messages

Comment: true, so you need to save the message somewhere say in SQLite db and when the activity by tapping notification is launched, retrieve the message from db and show them